# Шанс рандома на php

Tags: php, случайные-числа

Итак, мы имеем 6 чисел (123456). Нужно, чтобы у числа 1 и 2 был шанс выпадения 70%, а у 3456 шанс 30%.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать на php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$n = rand(1,1000);

if ($n <= 350) {
  echo 1;
} elseif ($n <= 700) {
  echo 2;
} elseif ($n <= 775) {
  echo 3;
} elseif ($n <= 850) {
  echo 4;
} elseif ($n <= 925) {
  echo 5;
} else {
  echo 6;
}
```

Comment: Я уже планировал такой вариант, но все равно спасибо.

Comment: @wiggy - Я очень извиняюсь, что это за хамский комментарий?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно

```
$v = rand(1,100) <= 70 ? rand (1, 2) : rand(3, 6);
```